# Digital Signature of Google Cloud Function response message

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-kms

I try to sign a response message using Google Cloud KMS.

But immediately get an error.

index.js:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const kms = require('@google-cloud/kms');

exports.helloKms = (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "@google-cloud/kms": "^1.5.3",
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

log:

```
2019-12-01T05:26:37.534Z kms-demo Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '@google-cloud/kms'
....
2019-12-01T05:26:37.599Z Cloud Functions UpdateFunction us-central1:kms-demo boristep@googlemail.com INVALID_ARGUMENT E  Cloud Functions UpdateFunction us-central1:kms-demo boristep@googlemail.com
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you actually installed the module properly.  If you just edited package.json the way you illustrated, that's not going to work.  You should `npm install @google-cloud/kms` to make sure package.json get installed properly.  It will appear in a block called "depenedencies" in your package.json, and new files will appear in node_modules.

You might want to take some time to learn about how npm works for package management.

Comment: I'm saying about cloud function. It is not a nodejs application

Comment: Cloud Functions actually deploys node applications, if that's the runtime you choose.  If you're deploying JavaScript, you are deploying it to a node container.  The way that dependencies are installed is not any different.